# Do I need to completely finish Season 1 before starting Season 2?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one, the-walking-dead-season-two

The second season of The Walking Dead episodic game has just been released. I've not yet finished all the episodes from season one.

Is the second season a continuation of the same story ( so may include spoilers ) or it is a totally separate story and is playable without ruining the ending of S1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes the second season of the walking dead is a direct continuation of the story from the end of the first season and I would imagine there will be some large spoilers from the end of season one that will become apparent almost immediately.

My advice is finish season one first.

I am not sure how the 400 days DLC ties into season 2, if at all. Maybe some one else could add that information.

Comment: It has been stated that your choices in the 400 Days DLC will feed into season 2.  However, given that playing the DLC is not a requirement, there must be some default choices that will occur if the DLC hasn't been played.  I imagine it will be more of a "hey cool, that's what I did" thing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't "have" to but I think it would not be a wise decision. They allow you to select a pre-set selection of "Decisions" if you choose not to play the first, but it is definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is recommended I just got season 2 for xbox and do not have season 1 that I have beat on mh phone and it says season 1 save not found and so I wasted money pretty muck unless I get season 1 which is out of stock like everywhere